# How to store dynamic form data in database laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My form is like this I have four-row in the database.

I'm trying to save a dynamic form in laravel. unable to save data array into the database. The following is the form.

I am struggling with working on a dynamic that was made out of Laravel 7 and ajax. I had followed some tutorials on youtube but I can seem to expand the toggle button when the screen size is reduced to the smallest. Since I'm starting a new project, I applied all of this with laravel 7 and ajax and opened the page file in my local directory. Please help me! I have been stuck for hours.

[image: dynamic]

How to save and update it?

Blade

```
@extends('Admin.master')

@section('content')

    <div class="p-5">
        <h3><i class="fas fa-link ml-2"></i>لینک ها</h3><hr>
        <form action="{{ route('links.store') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div id="showDynamic">

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ذخیره</button>
        </form>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('script')

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                let count = 1;
                dynamic();
                function dynamic() {
                    let html = '' +
                    '@foreach ($links as $link)\n'+
                    '<div class="row mb-2">\n' +
                    '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
                    '<input class="form-control" placeholder="عنوان" name="links['+count+'][title]" value="{{ $link->title }}">\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
                    '<input class="form-control" placeholder="لینک" name="links['+count+'][link]" value="{{ $link->link }}">\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '<div class="col-md-2">\n' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-primary add">افزودن</a>\n' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-danger delete">حذف</a>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '</div>\n';
                count++;
                html += '@endforeach';
                $('#showDynamic').append(html);
            }
            $(document).on('click' , '.add' , function(){
                count++;
                addDynamic(count);
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
            addDynamic(count);
            function addDynamic(number) {
                let html = '' +
                    '<div class="row mb-2">\n' +
                    '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
                    '<input class="form-control" placeholder="عنوان" name="links['+count+'][title]">\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
                    '<input class="form-control" placeholder="لینک" name="links['+count+'][link]">\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '<div class="col-md-2">\n' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-primary add">افزودن</a>\n' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-danger delete">حذف</a>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '<span class="d-none">count++</span>';
                $('#showDynamic').append(html);
            }
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request() , [
        'title' => 'required',
        'link' => 'required',
    ]);
    $links = collect([]);
    if ($request->links) {
        foreach ($request->links as $link) {
            $model = Link::updateOrCreate([
                'title' => $link['title']
            ], [
                'link' => $link['link'],
            ]);
            $links->push($model);
        }
    }
    Link::whereNotIn('id', $links->pluck('id'))->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Why have you put single quotes in your name property? here :  name="links['+count+']

Comment: Because I am using ajax. It is showing 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: And I updated my post...

Comment: So upon saving, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: After saving, I do not receive any errors.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?

Comment: Please post all three files of blade, ajax code and controller and link the share with me. I will look at them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228077/discussion-between-irankhostravi-and-ahmad-karimi).